# extracting the first retweets after a tweet's publication

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I try to extract "retweet cascades" from twitter, i.e. I want to chose a certain tweet and then extract its retweets. I know about the function `get_retweets()`, however this function only extracts the *most recent* retweets, while I want to have the *earliest* retweets. I also know that there is a limit on the number of retweets that can be extracted, so it is clear that I cannot just extract all the retweets and then sort them by their timestamp.
Is there a way to do this?

Eventually, I want to apply a Hawkins self-exciting process model, so it is essential to have the first retweets.